# angular2 conditional ng-template vs conditional div

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng-template

I am trying to figure out Angular2 structural directives and at the moment, I cannot spot the difference between a conditional `div` and a conditional `ng-template`.

Technically this code:

```
  <div *ngIf="true">
    <other-component></other-component>
  </div>
```

will do the same job with this code:

```
  <ng-template [ngIf]="true">
    <other-component></other-component>
  </ng-template>
```

According to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix) : "*The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more complicated. Internally, Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a `<ng-template>` element, wrapped around the host element..*"

Also, according to [Angular University Blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/) : "*Angular is already using ng-template under the hood in many of the structural directives that we use all the time: **ngIf**, **ngFor** and **ngSwitch***." (following the documentation above)

**So, when it comes to write the statement in html, in simple words which is one is the proper one to render content conditionally and why.** Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is if you can accomplish the task with `ngIf`, `ngFor` or `ngSwitch` then it is no need to use ng-template and overcomplicate the code. But if you need to such statements as `if else` in Angular, the most common way is to use `ng-template`. Like here:

```
<div class="lessons-list" *ngIf="lessons else loading">
  ... 
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
    <div>Loading...</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: @Olegl thank you for that. It seems that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on angular documents.

> The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more
>   complicated. Internally, Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a
>    element, wrapped around the host element, like this.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

> The *ngIf directive moved to the  element where it became
>   a property binding,[ngIf]. The rest of the , including its class
>   attribute, moved inside the  element.

[Read more here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Comment: thank you for the effort, I think I include the official documentation in the initial question. Although, I feel my question has not answered yet. Let's wait for other members to answer